# How to use raw_call in Vyper?

Tags: vyper

I am new to Vyper and am trying to use the raw_call built in function as defined in the official documentation.
I am getting the error where the vyper compiler says that the raw_call function expects 2 arguments and not 5. Is the official documentation wrong here or am I missing something? Would greatly appreciate some help
Please find the output and code screenshots attached.

[image: Output Screenshot:]

[image: My code:]

Comment: The images are low resolution and the text is unreadable. It is better to just use text to make it easier to test.

Answer (score 1):

Well there appears to be a difference between regular arguments and arguments with defaults (namely assigned arguments). I did not find documentation about it (maybe its pythonian^^)
So this answer is rather based on experience on how it appears to work:

The definition is [this](https://vyper.readthedocs.io/en/v0.2.8/built-in-functions.html#raw_call):

```
raw_call(to: address, data: Bytes, max_outsize: int = 0, gas: uint256 = gasLeft, value: uint256 = 0, is_delegate_call: bool = False, is_static_call: bool = False) → Bytes[max_outsize]
```

Here you may see:

```
to: address,
data: Bytes,

max_outsize: int = 0,
gas: uint256 = gasLeft,
value: uint256 = 0,
is_delegate_call: bool = False, 
is_static_call: bool = False
```

It appears that these arguments with defaults like `max_outsize` do not appear to count in the arguments count. Only the 2 arguments without default are being counted.

Funnily this also means you have to pass them differently - otherwise you get the the error you're having like `expects 2 arguments and not 5`.

To fix this you have to pass them like this:

```
_result:Bytes[32] = raw_call(
    _target_address,
    _call_data,
    max_outsize=32,
    gas=_max_gas,
    value=msg.value
)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you